How can I limit a "View Comments" link on a list item only when comments exist?

How can I limit the number of comments shows in the display?

The comment links here on SharePoint do not support display by condition at this time. There is no out-of-the-box solution for this issue at this time. Perhaps you can provide feedback about your issue on SharePoint Feedback portal.
